# How to make Android layout activity similar with instagrams image selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Am trying to create image selection activity layout similar with Instagram like below image.

[image]

But in my case when i add `RelativeLayout >> GridView`, the `image_button` and `camera_button` is will be pushed off the screen.

Please can anyone help how do I arrange the layout to give me expected result?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".imageEditClass"
    android:id="@+id/activity_image_edit_class">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.fenchtose.nocropper.CropperView
                android:background="#ff282828"
                android:id="@+id/croppingImagePreview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:nocropper__grid_opacity="0.8"
                app:nocropper__grid_thickness="0.8dp"
                app:nocropper__padding_color="@color/colorAccent"
                app:nocropper__grid_color="@color/colorAccent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/snap_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/black_transp_circ_ripple"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_crop_free_white_24dp"
                android:contentDescription="Crop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rotate_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/black_transp_circ_ripple"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rotate_right_white_24dp"
                android:contentDescription="Rotate" />

        </FrameLayout>


    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="211dp">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/galleryGridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="280dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp">

            </GridView>

        </RelativeLayout>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/galleryText"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/image_button"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/photoText"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/camera_button"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveText"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:id="@+id/crop_save_button"/>

        </GridLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Ali am not trying to clone or create instagram like app, only that image selection layout alike am trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your `GridLayout` to have 3 rows and 3 columns. You then provide a `RelativeLayout` containing a `GridView` as the first cell (position 0/0). You then provide a `Button` for "Gallery" which will be occupy position 0/1. You then provide a `Button` for "Photo" which will occupy position 0/2. Your "Save" `Button' will now occupy the cell at row 1, column 0. This isn't what you want.

Why do you have the `RelativeLayout` containing the `GridView` inside the `GridLayout`? It seems that you only need the `GridLayout` to evenly space the buttons at the bottom.

An alternative would be to indicate that the `RelativeLayout` should occupy 3 columns within the `GridLayout`, which would position the 3 buttons in the 3 cells of row index 1. You can do this by providing the `RelativeLayout` a `ColumnSpec` that has `columnSpan=3`. This tells the `GridLayout` that the `RelativeLayout` wants to be 3 cells (ie: the entire width of the row) wide.